# Issues with Bootstrap navbar-nav when using ngFor

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, navbar, ngfor

Hi I am using bootstrap v4.0.0. When displaying menus using navbar-nav and using ngFor, the bound property is called all the time - is this expected behavior?

HTML code snippet:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-content">
    <div class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let navItem of NavItems">          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="[navItem.url]" routerLinkActive="active" [target]="navItem.isLink ? '_blank' : null">{{navItem.displayName}}</a>
          </li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

component.ts code snippet:

```
private _navItems: object;
get NavItems() { // This API is called continuously even after the menu items are loaded
   if(!this._navItems){
    this._navItems=  [
      {
        "displayName": "TestApp",
        "url": "testApp",
        "isLink": false,
        "requiredRoles": [],
        "childNavs": []
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Custom Control",
        "url": "custom",
        "isLink": false,
        "requiredRoles": [],
        "childNavs": [
          {
            "displayName": "JQX Custom Grid",
            "url": "custom/grid",
            "isLink": true,
            "requiredRoles": []
          }
        ]
      }
    ];
   }
   return this._navItems;
  }
```

get NavItems binding is called all the time even when nothing has changed.

- Is this expected behavior?
- Is there a better approach?

Thanks,

RDV

Comment: Yes this is the expected behavior on angular due to change detection. You may wish to change that component to a different change detection strategy to on push. There are a lot articles and blog about this, here's one of them: https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angular-onpush-change-detection-strategy-5bac493074a4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on what @penleychan said, yes it is expected behaviour. Any value bound to a method in the template will call that method every change-detection cycle to ensure the value has not changed.

As far as I can tell, your getter method is essentially static, so you could just do:

```
private _navItems = 
[
      {
        "displayName": "TestApp",
        "url": "testApp",
        "isLink": false,
        "requiredRoles": [],
        "childNavs": []
      },
      {
        "displayName": "Custom Control",
        "url": "custom",
        "isLink": false,
        "requiredRoles": [],
        "childNavs": [
          {
            "displayName": "JQX Custom Grid",
            "url": "custom/grid",
            "isLink": true,
            "requiredRoles": []
          }
        ]
      }
];

public NavItems: object;

constructor() {
  this.NavItems = this._navItems;
}
```

If you are updating the value of `_navItems`, I suggest you just update `NavItems` afterwards and Angular will pick up that change.

Comment: Thanks @RJM, my _navItems is not constant, I read it from a file but it doesn't change after that. I liked your idea that I should read everything in _navItems and then only once update this.NavItems.